# How to create concrete class from a template class

Tags: c++, templates, concrete-inheritance

Say I have a template class:

```
template <typename T> class StringDeque:
public std::deque<T>
{
public:

    ...

private:
    typedef std::deque<T> BaseClass; 
};
```

Say I want to create concrete class `ArrayString` where `T=std::string`. 
What is the proper way to achieve that:

**define**

```
#define ArrayString StringDeque<string>
```

**typedef**

```
typedef StringDeque < string > ArrayString;
```

**inheritance**

```
class ArrayString :
    public StringDeque < string > {};
```

I'm not sure whether all of the suggestions are valid. Anyway I'm trying to figure out which practice most fits.

Comment: i don't think typedef works for templates, but you can say `using ArrayString = StringDeque<std::string>;`

Comment: @Melkon Typedef works on types, and an instantiation of a class template is a type, so it works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proper ways:

```
typedef std::deque<std::string> StringDeque;
using StringDeque = std::deque<string>;
```

That said, here are some more notes on your question:

You wrote:

```
template <typename T> class StringDeque: public std::deque<T> // ...
```

`std` container classes *are not meant as base classes*. This means they should not be inherited from (and inheriting from them is UB).

When you want to use `std` container functionality in another class, the answer should always be encapsulation. That means, the correct way to build on the functionality of std::queue in your classes is:

```
template<typename T> class StringDequeue {
    std::deque<T> storage;
public:
    // add interface here that uses storage
};
```

You also proposed this:

```
#define ArrayString StringDeque<string>
```

Please never use define to declare a type. It works, but it has it's own pitfalls and is considered bad practice in C++.

Answer (score 3):

You want to give a name to a particular type (which happens to be an instantiation of a template). The C++ way to give names (aliases) to types is with a typedef:

```
typedef StringDeque<string> ArrayString;
```

Or, since C++11, with an alias declaration:

```
using ArrayString = StringDeque<string>;
```

---

Side note: when thinking about this stuff, it generally helps to think in terms of the correct template terminology. You don't have a "template class" (a *class* with special properties), you have a "class template" (a *template* for creating classes). The template is not a type; its instantiations are.

Answer (score 1):

Create type aliases with `typedef` or (since C++11) `using`:

```
typedef StringDeque<std::string> ArrayString;
using ArrayString = StringDeque<std::string>;
```

The preprocessor is a sledgehammer: occasionally useful but, with no knowledge of language-level constructs, prone to break code in surprising ways. In this case, I think the only problem is that the name won't be constrained to any scope; but that's reason enough to avoid it.

Inheritance creates a new type; while it's usually usable where the base type is, it's not completely interchangable, and doesn't inherit any constructors from the base type. So that's also not what you want for a simple type alias.